# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column and in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I have two table the `Tbl_payroll_leave_employeev2` and `tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2` and i want to `join` them but im getting an error like this

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'payroll_leave_employee_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `payroll_employee_id` from `tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2` inner join `tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2` on `tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2`.`payroll_leave_employee_id` = `tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2`.`payroll_leave_employee_id` where `payroll_leave_employee_id` = 5) ◀

My table structure
[image]

```php
$employee_id = Tbl_payroll_leave_employeev2::select('payroll_employee_id')
   ->join('tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2','tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2.payroll_leave_employee_id','=','tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2.payroll_leave_employee_id')
   ->where('payroll_leave_employee_id',$emp)
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In where condition,  you must define the field `payroll_leave_employee_id` of table `tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2`  or table `tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2`

```php
$employee_id = Tbl_payroll_leave_employeev2::select('payroll_employee_id')
   ->join('tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2','tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2.payroll_leave_employee_id','=','tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2.payroll_leave_employee_id')
   ->where('tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2.payroll_leave_employee_id',$emp)
   ->get();
```

Comment: @dieuhd what if we have 2 column to compare (beside id), i.e `tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2.payroll_leave_employee_date = tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2.payroll_leave_employee_date` ?